# Show that $S=\mathbb{R}\setminus \left \{-1 \right \}$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Can someone please give me a hint on how to solve this?

> Let $S=\mathbb{R}\setminus \left \{ -1  \right \}$ and define a binary operation on $S$ by $a\circ b=a+b+ab$. Prove that $(S,\circ)$ is an abelian group.

I cannot just say $a\circ b=a+b+ab=b+a+ba=b\circ a$, so what should I do?

Comment: You _can_ just say that, and it proves that the operation is commutative. It remains to show that it is a _group_.

Comment: Arthur is completely right. Also, another nice way to see this is that $a\circ b = (a+1)(b+1)-1$, so $\circ$ is just the usual product on $\Bbb{R}$ (which is abelian), where you first increment the inputs and then decrement back. I.e.\ this group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. Not to say that what you've written isn't probably the shortest and easiest proof ofc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must verify all of the abelian group axioms. You have shown that this binary operation is commutative, but it remains to show:

- This binary operation takes pairs of elements in the set, to another element *in* the set,
- This is an associative binary operation,
- An identity exists in the set,
- An inverse element exists in the set.

One is certainly allowed to utilise information about the field $\Bbb R$ to generate this proof.